# "Hot Meta Posts" box title and post score almost unreadable

Tags: bug, status-completed, design

[image: Here are a number of words to enlighten people who cannot see the image as to the sadness that this new Hot Meta Posts box is in its dark-grey-on-slightly-darker gray action. It is nigh unreadable.] [image: Can this please be fixed? Pretty please.]

:(

Comment: [Here I fixed it](http://i.imgur.com/5tD8c0X.png)

Comment: @BenBrocka Have I been holding it wrong all along?

Comment: ...speaking of, the visited link text color is barely different from the non-link text on beta

Comment: status-completed?

Answer (score 1):

Somebody, somewhere, fixed this. Hooray!